# Something very basic in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and I need to detect whenever someone enters to my site with the Interent Explorer Browser. So, I made the following code and the div that I created is being scripted on other web browsers I assume the problem is with the .getElementById or such.
So after the talking, here's the code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var browserName=navigator.appName; 
if (browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
document.getElementById("example");  
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id ="example">You're Using Interent Explorer. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks alot for helpers.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the element you're searching for...  What is the intent of that function?  More importantly, why are you detecting IE?  This can be done with HTML comments, i.e. `<!--[if IE]>
      <div>blah</div>
    <![endif]-->`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These HTML comments are only rendered by internet explorer

```
<body>
<!--[if IE]>
    <div id ="example">You're Using Interent Explorer. </div>
<![endif]-->
</body>
```

most of the time it's for CSS, because you can target IE 6,7,8,etc or greater than IE 7:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/NYUwC/)

Comment: @Fosco: Nobody is using jQuery here in fact :)

Comment: @EdwardDaker yes no Javascript is required. see my pastebin in the previous answer.

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory Uhm, can you explain me why the following code doesn't work then? http://pastebin.com/EZKRuT3A

Comment: @EdwardDaker, that code has the style display: none; so it will never display

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory Well, I don't really want to create an external css files, so I made this: why is it not working? it's just like you said. http://pastebin.com/fjZewYj3

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory I'm sorry, my bad it should've been display:block but now I just changed it and I can see the div in chrome also.

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory That's right, but the weird thing is that I see it on chrome too, i really don't know why

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory OMG, I'm so stupid, I didn't look at the right place, it was working all that time.. I'm really sorry for wasting your time!! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory I'm sorry I don't have enough rate to upvote your answer but really, thanks alot!!

Answer (score 4):

1 To begin with, you should hide the div (`display:none`).

2 You need to actually do something with the div in your script ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CMJ9d/1)).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
        {
            document.getElementById("example").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id ="example" style="display:none;">You're Using Interent Explorer. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise, you could just add the div contextually ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdUgd/))

```
window.onload = function(){
    if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
        document.body.appendChild(
            document.createElement("div")
        ).appendChild(
            document.createTextNode("You're Using Interent Explorer"));
    }
}
```

Comment: you also need to run on document ready or the script will run before the div is on the page

Comment: Alternatively you could you conditional tags to load in IE specific css to show/hide that div.

Comment: @antisainty Thanks alot, I think I understood this problem, but it's still not working, mind explaining what scrappedcola said please?

Comment: @AlistairLaing I really hate asking this but I really need this asap, do you mind uploading a pastebin file please?

Comment: @EdwardDaker if you use this method least you knwo that it would work if the user had javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JavaScript should not be used to detect browsers. Like, for Chrome, it gives the result "Netscape". Anyways to answer your question, what about an alternative:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var browserName=navigator.appName; 
if (browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML="You're using Internet Explorer!";  
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id ="example"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What it does is it will have no content in the specific div element, that is, example. Only if JavaScript detects that one is using Internet Explorer, it writes "You're using IE" in the div element. For example, you can check out http://www.ducksearch.in/ using Internet Explorer. It shows an alert box that some features may be missing if you use IE. Very basic JavaScript, indeed :)

Good luck on your way ahead, and all the best coding in JavaScript.